# Evaluation of sympy.function containing a NumPy function

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

My problem is that the following code doesn't evaluate the function `f`

```
class f(sympy.Function):
    @staticmethod
    def _imp_(x):
        return numpy.sin(x)  # shows f(0.1) 
        # return sympy.sin(x)  # shows 0.0998334166468282

print f(0.1)
```

numerically when I use inside the `_imp_` function numpy procedures. But it works well when I use sympy only. What is wrong at here?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong.

The precision is due to floating point numbers.

Check [here](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/mpmath/technical.html) and [here](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/mpmath/basics.html) ,where you can set the precision.

Comment: Hmm.. I don't need to change the precision of floating point operations. I just need to evaluate the function's value numerically. I want that `print f(0.1)` shows the numerical result, not symbolic.

Comment: @Maksim Surov:But sympy  gives you the numerical result..It just isn't as 'accurate' as python.

Comment: `sympy.sin` gives the result. But my question is why `numpy.sin` doesn't give the result. Anyway, I found the answer.

Comment: @Maksim Surov:Sorry , I misunderstood ,but you didn't write clean what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The explicit type conversion fixed my problem:

```
def _imp_(x):
    return numpy.sin(float(x))
```